# How to change font in Framebuffer in Linux using C?

Tags: c, linux, framebuffer

I have a graphic application under development but I am unable to change the font in that. If anyone knows about any page or link explaining the method to change fonts in framebuffer on linux, it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux frame buffer is a memory location which is mapped to your display area. What ever you write in to this memory area that reflects on the display. Coming to your question, For frame buffer there is nothing like font. every thing is a binary data. For making your own font, first you need to get hexadecimal values corresponding to your characters then write that data into frame buffer at required location. Or you can use some api like X11, MiniGUI or Qt, which provides simple way to write data into frame buffer devices.